# How to decide which spring components should be added into application context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need a mechanism to descide which components should be included into the application context. Currently, I use @Import for it. Whether it works, @Import is for @Configuration only. Is there an alternative?

**EDIT:**

I use @ComponentScan to register spring beans and components. I have a directory with controllers annotated with @Controller. For testing purpose I do not want to register all controllers, but only specific. Can I use something like

Currently I use

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true){/*testings*/}

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {AccountsRepository.class, LogoutService.class})
@Import({AccountCommandsController.class})
public class TestConfiguration {}
```

@Import works for me, but its for Configurations only, not for registering controller components. Is there an equaliant for controllers or components?

Comment: Profiles? Import selectors? Please be more specific about what you need.

Comment: Any reason not to declare specific beans in your test configuration?

Comment: I only know "@ComponentScan" for registering beans, and "@Bean" of course. How to declare specific beans only?

Comment: Just use `@Bean` with your controller classes.

Answer (score 0):

If are using Spring 3.1 you should really be using [Spring Profiles](http://diarmuidmoloney.wordpress.com/2012/04/07/spring-environments/) for situations where you conditionally need to include beans in the application context. It makes setting up tests very easy

If you are using Spring 4 and your needs are not covered by profiles, you can look into Spring's @Conditional [support](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/)

If you use that way, there is no need to use `@Include`. Just have regular `@Configuration` classes where either the whole class is annotated with `@Profile` or specific `@Bean` methods (only supported in Spring 4)

You can then activate whatever profiles the specific test requires by using `@ActiveProfiles`